# SQL Audit including SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP recording audit record for every bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, audit-logging

Enabled SQL Audit on an Azure SQL Managed Instance with the intent to capture DDL changes to tables, stored procedures, functions etc. Upon testing discovered that `SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP` captures audit data for bulk inserts (it also captures truncate table commands but that isn't an issue here).

The instance in question services significant amounts of bulk inserts and the audit uses unwanted system resources and blob storage. Is there a way to exclude bulk inserts in a SQL Audit?

```sql
CREATE SERVER AUDIT [Audit-DDL]
TO URL ( PATH = 'https://blobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/sqlaudit', RETENTION_DAYS = 7)
WITH (QUEUE_DELAY = 1000, ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE)

CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [Spec-DDL]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [Audit-DDL]
    ADD (DATABASE_CHANGE_GROUP),
    ADD (DATABASE_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP)
    ADD (SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP)
WITH (STATE=ON)
```

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done on "group" level,but you can probably specify the actions you're interested in by creating specific actions to audit

Comment: BULK INSERT and TRUNCATE are unfortunately among some gray-area DDL operations, so they are captured by that group. There is no `SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_EXCEPT_BULK_INSERT_GROUP`, so you'll have to be more granular.